# How to read file which contains \uxxxx in vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have txt file whose contents are:

> \u041f\u0435\u0440\u0432\u044b\u0439_\u0438\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0430\u043a\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u044b\u0439_\u0438\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u043d\u0435\u0442_\u043a\u0430\u043d\u0430\u043b

How can I read such file to get result like this:

> "Первый_интерактивный_интернет_канал"

If I type this:

```
string str = _T("\u041f\u0435\u0440\u0432\u044b\u0439_\u0438\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0430\u043a\u0442\u0438\u0432\u043d\u044b\u0439_\u0438\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u043d\u0435\u0442_\u043a\u0430\u043d\u0430\u043b");
```

then result in `str` is good but if I read it from file then it is the same like in file. I guess it is because '\u' becomes '\u'.
Is there simple way to convert \uxxxx notation to corresponding symbols in C++?

Comment: Don't use `std::string` on Windows. —Does the file really contains these escape sequences, e.g. if you open it in Notepad?

Comment: Yes file contents looks the same as i posted in question.

Comment: OK, then follow MSalters's advice. And please use code formatting (four-space indent): I know that you're using the macro `_T` but that is not visible in your question because it's converted to italic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for MSalters's suggestion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>

#include <boost/scoped_array.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/conversion/cast.hpp>

std::wstring convert_unicode_escape_sequences(const std::string& source) {
  const boost::regex regex("\\\\u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})");  // NB: no support for non-BMP characters
  boost::scoped_array<wchar_t> buffer(new wchar_t[source.size()]);
  wchar_t* const output_begin = buffer.get();
  wchar_t* output_iter = output_begin;
  std::string::const_iterator last_match = source.begin();
  for (boost::sregex_iterator input_iter(source.begin(), source.end(), regex), input_end; input_iter != input_end; ++input_iter) {
    const boost::smatch& match = *input_iter;
    output_iter = std::copy(match.prefix().first, match.prefix().second, output_iter);
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << std::hex << match[1].str() << std::ends;
    unsigned int value;
    stream >> value;
    *output_iter++ = boost::numeric_cast<wchar_t>(value);
    last_match = match[0].second;
  }
  output_iter = std::copy(last_match, source.end(), output_iter);
  return std::wstring(output_begin, output_iter);
}

int wmain() {
  std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
  const std::wstring filename = L"test.txt";
  std::ifstream stream(filename.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  stream.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
  const std::ifstream::streampos size = stream.tellg();
  stream.seekg(0);
  boost::scoped_array<char> buffer(new char[size]);
  stream.read(buffer.get(), size);
  const std::string source(buffer.get(), size);
  const std::wstring result = convert_unicode_escape_sequences(source);
  std::wcout << result << std::endl;
}
```

I'm always surprised how complicated seemingly simple things like this are in C++.

Comment: I think you've got a spurious w in `const std::wstring filename = "test.txt";`. Also, why the insanely complex file reading? It seems you can trivially write a `while(std::string line = getline(stream)) { }`, with an ordinary text stream. Converting the \uXXXX escapes can then be done line by line.

Comment: The `wstring filename` is deliberate (I just forgot the `L` prefix) to allow Unicode filenames on Windows. AFAIK `ifstream` contains an appropriate, nonstandard constructor. Regarding the file reading, I think it's the most straightforward way to read a complete file, given the ridiculously limited iostream API. Readine line-by-line is a bit shorter, but still a workaround.

Comment: what is the difference between `std::wstring` and `std::string`?

Answer (score 2):

It's not very easy when you're reading in the file. It's easier to do a post-processing step afterwards. You can use `Boost::regex` to look for the pattern "\u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}", and replace that by the corresponding single character.

Comment: This is how I'd do it, and seems to be the only answer so far which is actually related to the question. However, if the file can contain non-BMP characters, the regex has to be modified a bit, e.g. `\\u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4,6}`.

Comment: Depends on how those characters would be encoded. A \u escape isn't entirely standard. I've seen \U00XXXXXX as well.

Answer (score 0):

My solution. I used Boost for UTF-16 - UTF-8 conversion.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>
#include <boost/numeric/conversion/cast.hpp>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

inline uint8_t get_uint8(uint8_t h, uint8_t l)
{
    uint8_t ret;

    if (h - '0' < 10)
        ret = h - '0';
    else if (h - 'A' < 6)
        ret = h - 'A' + 0x0A;
    else if (h - 'a' < 6)
        ret = h - 'a' + 0x0A;

    ret = ret << 4;

    if (l - '0' < 10)
        ret |= l - '0';
    else if (l - 'A' < 6)
        ret |= l - 'A' + 0x0A;
    else if (l - 'a' < 6)
        ret |= l - 'a' + 0x0A;
    return  ret;
}

std::string convert_unicode_escape_sequences(const std::string& source) 
{
    std::wstring ws; ws.reserve(source.size());
    std::wstringstream wis(ws);

    auto s = source.begin();
    while (s != source.end())
    {
        if (*s == '\\')
        {
            if (std::distance(s, source.end()) > 5)
            {
                if (*(s + 1) == 'u')
                {
                    unsigned int v = get_uint8(*(s + 2), *(s + 3)) << 8;
                    v |= get_uint8(*(s + 4), *(s + 5));

                    s += 6;
                    wis << boost::numeric_cast<wchar_t>(v);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        wis << wchar_t(*s);
        s++;
    }

    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
    return myconv.to_bytes(wis.str());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this code :) Windows SDK has it already for you, MS geeks thought for this too, you can find more details in this post: http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2008/07/24/visual-c-in-short-converting-between-unicode-and-utf-8.aspx

```
#include <atlconv.h>
#include <atlstr.h>

#define ASSERT ATLASSERT

int main()
{
    const CStringW unicode1 = L"\u041f and \x03A9"; // 'Alpha' and 'Omega'

    const CStringA utf8 = CW2A(unicode1, CP_UTF8);

    ASSERT(utf8.GetLength() > unicode1.GetLength());

    const CStringW unicode2 = CA2W(utf8, CP_UTF8);

    ASSERT(unicode1 == unicode2);   

    return 0;
}
```

This code has been tested by me and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, but i had tried it and no luck, i dont think it is encoding problem. OK for example i have CString a = "\\uXXXX" now how make variable a to have char of \uXXXX using 'utfcpp', is it possible?

Comment: @garzanti: Why do you want to mess around with UTF-8 at all?

Comment: problem is i dont have this: 
const CStringW unicode1 = L"\u041f"
i have this: const CStringW unicode1 = L"\\u041f" (double esc sequence)

Comment: @Philipp: What exactly I am messing with UTF-8? His string is an UTF-16, and here it is just a sample showing what it can do. From my point of view it's ok. I think you are just exagerating. 

Give a solution yourself please first, before critcizing, or at least make fair comment saying what exactly is not ok, instead of sarcastic statements.

Comment: @Velutis In your initial question it wasn't any double esc sequence :) so... sincerly I have no solution in this case. What you could do is to replace the double backslashes with one, using regular expressions for example.

Comment: @garzanti: Your code contains a fine example of how to convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8 and back using ATL functions. However, this is just not related to the question, which requires conversions from Unicode escape sequences to UTF-16.