# How to convert a unicode string to its unicode escapes?

Tags: c++, qt, unicode

Say I have a text "Բարև Hello Здравствуй". (I save this code in QString, but if you know other way to store this text in c++ code, you'r welcome.) How can I convert this text to Unicode escapes like this "\u1330\u1377\u1408\u1415 Hello \u1047\u1076\u1088\u1072\u1074\u1089\u1090\u1074\u1091\u1081" (see [here](http://doc.infosnel.nl/extreme_utf-8.html))?

Comment: `QString` is fine. As an alternative, you could use `UnicodeString` from the ICU library.

Comment: That is not "UTF-8 code", in fact your example has nothing to do with UTF-8 at all. What you're describing are Unicode escapes. And as far as I know they are not universally used. Java uses them in its source files, for example.

Comment: OK I change code->unicode escapes!

Comment: I don't see anything related to UTF-8 in your question. `QString` uses the UTF-16 encoding, and the desired result seems to be the representation using escape sequences for non-ASCII characters. Interestingly, this question seems to be the inverse of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147900.

Comment: Seams it is only by default. But you can set it to UTF-8 or to other encoding.

Comment: No, you cannot change it, but you can *convert* from UTF-8.

Comment: also, on "\uxxxx" escapes, see http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/11685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem with this code:

EDITED TO A BETTER VERSION: (I just do not want to convert Latin symbols to Unicode, because it will consume additional space without and advantage for my problem (want to remind that I want to generate Unicode RTF)).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
    QString str(QWidget::tr("Բարև (1-2+3/15,69_) Hello {} [2.63] Здравствуй"));
    QString strNew;

    QString isAcsii;
    QString tmp;
    foreach(QChar cr, str)
    {
        if(cr.toAscii() != QChar(0))
        {
            isAcsii = static_cast<QString>(cr.toAscii());
            strNew+=isAcsii;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp.setNum(cr.unicode());
            tmp.prepend("\\u");
            strNew+=tmp;
        }
    }
    QMessageBox::about(0,"Unicode escapes!",strNew);
    return app.exec();
}
```

Thanks to @Daniel Earwicker for the algorithm and of course +1.

BTW you need to specify UTF-8 for text editor encoding.

Comment: Actually you could just use `QString::fromUtf8("Բարև (1-2+3/15,69_) Hello {} [2.63] Здравствуй")`

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <cstdio>

#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtCore/QTextStream>

int main() {
  QString str = QString::fromWCharArray(L"Բարև Hello Здравствуй");
  QString escaped;
  escaped.reserve(6 * str.size());
  for (QString::const_iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it) {
    QChar ch = *it;
    ushort code = ch.unicode();
    if (code < 0x80) {
      escaped += ch;
    } else {
      escaped += "\\u";
      escaped += QString::number(code, 16).rightJustified(4, '0');
    }
  }
  QTextStream stream(stdout);
  stream << escaped << '\n';
}
```

Note this loops over UTF-16 code units, not actual code points.

Comment: I am getting linkage error. It is because ch.unicode() I guess.

Comment: Link with `QtCore` (e.g. `g++ -lQtCore`).

Comment: also QString::fromWCharArray causes the following problem:
error: converting to execution character set: Illegal byte sequence

Comment: @Narek: Yes, I tested it before posting. (Sometimes I write code off my head, but this code would be way too complicated.)
I also tested the result in Python, which uses the same escapement mechanism, and the input string was returned. Please specify your compiler and operating system. Mine is GCC 4.3.3 on Linux.

Comment: Should nevertheless work. Maybe you need to specify the encoding of the source code explicitly to use the wide string.

Comment: I do not know how to make this to work for me (anyway I have accomplished the task in represented way), but anyway this may be a variant for the other readrs, thus +1 and thanks Philip for your help!

Comment: Depending on what you'll be using it for, you might also want to convert any single slash (\) from the original 'str' into two slashes (\\) in the 'escaped' string, so that you can de-escape it properly later.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're doing code-generation (of JavaScript, maybe?)

`QString` is like a collection of `QChar`. Loop through the contents, and on each `QChar` call the `unicode` method to get the `ushort` (16-bit integer) value.

Then format each character like `"\\u%04X"`, i.e. `\u` followed by the 4-digit hex value.

NB. You may need to swap the two bytes (the two hex characters) to get the right result depending on the platform you're running on.

Comment: Not sure if this works outside the BMP. How are characters like U+10000 encoded in RTF files?

Comment: The code is not readable, please use code formatting (simply edit your original question). And again it's nothing to do with UTF-8, so I'm quite sure you don't need the `setCodecForTr` stuff.

Comment: Hi Narek, if you get an error message from your tools, it's a good idea to post the text of it so people can help you.

Comment: Also you appear to be trying to use my suggested format string by passing it as a string to a stream. That will just output it as a string. I wrote the format string in the old `sprintf` style, so you could try using that, or you could look up how to do it with `std::stringstream`.

Answer (score 2):

```
wchar_t *input;
wstring output; 

for (int i=0; i<str_len; i++)
{
  wchar_t code[7];
  swprintf(code, 7, L"\\u%0.4X",input[i]);
  output += code;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first determine which Coding is used for the text "Բարև Hello Здравствуй", looks like Russian, may be Win Code Page 1251. OR  UTF-8 or something else.
Then Use window function MultiByteToWideChar with required inputs such as Applied Code page, OriginalName, etc.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
std::wstring output;
QString result;

QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale ( QTextCodec::codecForName ( "UTF-8" ) );

for( uint i = 0; wcslen( input ) > i; ++i )
{
    if( isascii( input[ i ] ) )
    {
        output.reserve( output.size() + 1 );
        output += input[ i ];
    } else {
        wchar_t code[ 7 ];
        swprintf( code, 7, L"\\u%0.4X", input[ i ] );
        output.reserve( output.size() + 7 ); // "\u"(2) + 5(uint max digits capacity)
        output += code;
    }
}

result.reserve( output.size() );
result.append( QString::fromStdWString( output ) );
```

Works with Russian correct.
Transforms

```
hello
привет
```

into

```
hello
\\u043F\\u0440\\u0438\\u0432\\u0435\\u0442
```