# How to print unicode characters using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, unicode

I'm trying to do something very simple, I just want to print my native language, pt-br in Windows Console.

IDE Creator
I created a new project->other->Qt Console Application the I put it in my main.cpp file:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication  a(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "aeiou áéíóú";
    std::cout << "aeiou áéíóú" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

here is what I got:

```
C:\Users\maiko.costa\testeQtConsole\debug>testeQtConsole.exe
aeiou ßÚÝ¾·
aeiou ßÚÝ¾·

C:\Users\maiko.costa\testeQtConsole\debug>
```

I've tried it too, but with the same previous output:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication  a(argc, argv);

    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("CP1252");
    QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(codec);

    qDebug() << "aeiou áéíóú";
    std::cout << "aeiou áéíóú" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The System  encode for Windows 7 is it right ?

what am I missing ?

Comment: Perhaps check out [QLocale](http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/qt4/qlocale.html)?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the non-ASCII characters in the string literals?

Comment: QLocale didn't change anything.

@pezcode did you mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211214/how-to-convert-a-unicode-string-to-its-unicode-escapes ?

Comment: @MaikoID yes. Not sure which compiler you're using, but unescaped non-ASCII literals are not guaranteed by the C++ standard. IIRC VS only allows those inside `wchar_t` literals (`L""`)

Answer (score 1):

I am not that familiar with QT but I think this can help you just as well. The Windows console uses the OEM char set. Therefore, in order to properly print characters on std::cout they need to be encoded using OEM. This can be accomplished using the Windows API CharToOem.

Small example, just so you get the idea (here input is assumed to be UTF16):

```
void oemPrint(const wchar_t* str) {
    char* chars = (char*)alloca(strlen(str)+1);
    CharToOemW(str, chars);
    fputs(chars, stdout);
}

// Usage:
oemPrint(L"aeiou áéíóú");
```

EDIT: A QT solution might be to use QTextCodec::codecForName("IBM 850") - this is the OEM codec.

Comment: You also have to check the source code encoding and the compiler's documentation to make sure that the string litteral is correctly interpreted before it is encoded for output.

Comment: Yes, that is why I wrote "here input is assumed to be UTF16". It is just an example.

Comment: The Windows console is Unicode and the console subsystem will do any codepage conversions for you. Besides, the codepage *only* applies if you select a raster font for the console.

Comment: @Joey No, it is OEM. Try printing UTF16 or UTF8 directly to std::cout. It will not work.

Comment: CP 850 isn't the universal OEM codepage, though. In Europe 437 is normal and other parts of the world have different ones as well. And the whole OEM/Unicode thing smells more like a C++ iostream problem than a limitation of the Windows console – WriteConsoleW *does* write Unicode, even to a console that has a different charset (if using Raster fonts conversion is performed by Windows).

Comment: Granted OEM, can be other code pages. WriteConsole does perform this conversion and might be simpler if std::cout isn't a requirement. The [doc page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401(v=vs.85).aspx) for that function explains that the default char set indeed is OEM apparently you can change this using SetConsoleCP. Using this function might be the best solution.

Comment: Hi, I've tried everything in this page without success. I've found a interesting post in qtforum and the guy couldn't do too. I'm waiting any answer here or there.   http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/2344-Unicode-on-(Win32)-console?p=213823#post213823

Comment: It didn't compile. I can't find which headers are you using.

Comment: Includes: malloc.h, windows.h, stdio.h, string.h

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution in this thread. [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492077/output-unicode-strings-in-windows-console-app)

If I ran `chcp 65001` in windows console before I ran my app the characters are printed correctly.

I don't know how to workaround it in my source code, then I call this program manually with the start cpp function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the return line of function I wrote that displays passwords as ● ● ● ● ●

```
return QString::fromUtf8( "\u25CF \u25CF \u25CF \u25CF \u25CF" );
```

QString::fromUnicode should work the same.

Maybe something like:

```
QString x = QString::fromUtf8( "\u25CF \u25CF \u25CF \u25CF \u25CF" );
std::cout << qPrintable(x) << std::endl;
```

Of course change it to QString::fromUnicode... hope this helps

Comment: did you know any way of automatic convert my strings to escaped strings ?

Answer (score -1):

```
QString a="aeiou áéíóú";
std::cout<< a.toStdString().data();
```