# Replace backslashes from unicode escaped string

Tags: qt, unicode, utf-8, qnetworkaccessmanager, qbytearray

I want to send POST request using `QNetworkAccessManager::post` method, however my JSON have some international characters like *ąę*.

Unfortunately my WebAPI have some problems with decoding this string from `QByteArray` format: `"\xC4\x99\xC4\x85"`.

With `curl` my API works fine with not escaped string and with unicode escaped string: `\u0119\u0105`.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3212012/3826400) but after I convert `QString` to unicode escaped `QString`:

```
QString toUnicodeEscaped(const QString& str){
    QString escaped;
    escaped.reserve(6 * str.size());
    for (QString::const_iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it) {
        QChar ch = *it;
        ushort code = ch.unicode();
        if (code < 0x80) {
            escaped += ch;
        } else {
            escaped += "\\u";
            escaped += QString::number(code, 16).rightJustified(4, '0');
        }
    }
    return escaped;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString s = "ęą";
    qDebug() << "s: " << toUnicodeEscaped(s);
}
```

I got string with two backslashes:

```
s:  "\\u0119\\u0105"
```

I tried to replace two backslashes with one backslash but with no success:

```
qDebug() << "s: " << toUnicodeEscaped(s).replace("\\\\","\\");
```

How can I replace them?

Answer (score 0):

`"\xc4\x85\xc4\x99"` is `"ąę"` encoded as UTF-8, to convert this to a `QString`, use `QString::fromUtf8`.

The standard requires JSON to be encoded as UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32 so normally there's no confusion about what encoding was used. If your web API is implemented properly you don't have to escape those characters.