# How can I unescape a C-escaped Unicode string using C++?

Tags: c++, boost, unicode, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read file which contains \uxxxx in vc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147900/how-to-read-file-which-contains-uxxxx-in-vc)

I have a string like this:

```
string _str1("\\u6e05\\u534e\\u5927\\u5b66");
```

those _str1 s come from HTTP GET requests; they consist of C-escaped Unicode characters. I wish to unescape them, resulting in the actual character codes being stored in the string, as if I'd written,

```
string _str2("\u6e05\u534e\u5927\u5b66");
```

...and allowed the compiler to parse them out. So the desired result is a string containing `清华大学`.

(note that there was a bit of confusion with the original question - I DON'T want something like `u6e05u534eu5927u5b66` as the end-result!)

`-----edited--23/Feb----`

In my http response header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="\u6e05\u534e\u5927\u5b66.doc"
```

Filename here is generated by:

```
send_file c.candy.path, :filename => c.original_name.force_encoding('utf-8').to_json, :stream => true, :buffer_size => 4096
```

from my rails server.

In my cpp client, i got the same string as _str1 showed above.

**`My solution`**

I choose [JSON Spirit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20027/JSON-Spirit-A-C-JSON-Parser-Generator-Implemented/) to parse json strings.

When you have strings like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="\u6e05\u534e\u5927\u5b66.doc"
```

say, it's _str1.

```
wstring _str2 = string2wstring(_str1);
wValue _value;
read_string(_str2, _value);
const wObject& _object = _value.get_obj();
for( wObject::size_type i = 0; i != _object.size(); ++i )
{
    const wPair& pair = _object[i];
    const wstring& _p_name  = pair.name_;
    const wValue&  _p_value = pair.value_;

    if( L"original_name" == _p_name )
    {
        wstring _wtemp = _p_value.get_str();
    string _desired_string = wstring2string(_wtemp);
    }
    ... ...
    else
    {
        assert( false );
    }
} // for
```

Json spirit currently only parse wstring which contains "\u" normally.

Thanks to @bobince and @Shog9 !

Comment: @Jon you wrong, i replaced the string. and i got "u6e05u534eu5927u5b66"

Comment: You'd have to parse the string yourself, and replace the \uXXXX with the unicode character. Not hard, but not trivial either.

Comment: So what *should* the result be?

Comment: @iuwei: "I replaced the string" does not tell us what you *actually did*.

Comment: @Jon it's more like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369344/how-to-unescape-strings-in-c-c)

Comment: Ok, so this is not about escaping or unescaping or replacing parts of strings at all.  It's about parsing and outputting unicode strings.  I'd like to petition for a reopen based on that.

Comment: @KazDragon how to do that parse?

Comment: @Kaz Can you edit to clarify that point? That is not at all clear from the current text.

Comment: @iuwei: please see Philipp's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147900/how-to-read-file-which-contains-uxxxx-in-vc) - his `convert_unicode_escape_sequences()` function should do what you ask.

Comment: Given that this is coming from the web, are you sure it isn't JSON? It seems unlikely to be C; there are differences between the exact syntaxes for these two languages (and others that use `\u`-escapes). You should use a parser appropriate to the language you're actually getting.

Comment: @bobince makes an excellent point (I sorta wondered where you'd be getting C-encoded strings...) You might want to look over the questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20json?sort=faq), iuwei.